# modify the coordinate of a polygon svg.js

Tags: svg.js

How I can modify the coordinate of a polygon because the x and y property are readOnly

zones.js:168 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'x' property on 'SVGPoint': This object is read-only.

```
polygon.animatedPoints[0].x = 0;
polygon.animatedPoints[0].y = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution, use the points list

```
polygon.points[0].x = 0;
polygon.points[0].y = 0;
```